# Android:Elapsed time of an activity in foreground

Tags: android

in my current android project i'm trying to calculate an activities elapsed time in the foreground. I've found few functions in [this site](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/os/BatteryStats.Uid.Proc.html#getForegroundTime%28int%29).

Are these built in functions which just returns the time or should i have to define these methods in some other class? 
Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can take time of your activity in foreground in a hack simple way without any libraries.... Just **@Override OnPause()** - where you get the current time, and then when application returns from foreground **@Override OnResume()** where you get the current time too... Then just calculate the difference!!)) You can save cur.times in sharedPrefs for example, and in OnDestroy() set them in null!!)

Comment: I'm not calculating the elapsed time of my activity. For example, say twitter app is in the foreground. I need to find the elapsed time of this twitter app until i hits background. Please Help.